# Can you do a struts2 action redirect using POST instead of GET?

Tags: post, redirect, struts2, struts, action

```
<action name="actionA" class="com.company.Someaction">
 <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
  <param name="actionName">OtherActionparam>
  <param name="paramA">${someParams}</param>
  <param name="paramB">${someParams}</param>
  <param name="aBoatLoadOfOtherParams">${aBoatLoadOfOtherParams}</param>
 </result>
</action>
```

In the above action map, I am redirecting from SomeAction to OtherAction.  I am having issues, because unfortunately I need to pass a large amount of data between the two actions.  IE7 will only allow GET requests to be like 2k, so its blowing up when I'm just over that limit when the response calls a get request to the other action.

Is it possible for me to set this redirect, to end up with a POST being called to the other action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/redirect-result.html) states:

> The only way to pass data [after a redirection] is through
>   the session or with web parameters (url?name=value) [i.e., query string for a GET request]

Perhaps a case for [**action chaining**](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-chaining.html)? I'm not sure, and it's not usually recommended, but it seems that you scenario is rather unusual, so it might pay to take a look.

In this case, we are not really making a redirection, i.e., we are not going back to the client, but keeping everything inside the server. Supposedly, then, the full interceptor stack is executed again - and the posted data should impact on the new action, one would hope...

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm going to try Action Chaining.