# How to redirect action with parameter as post in Struts?

Tags: post, parameters, struts2

Redirect action to another action `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="CheckLogin" class="LoginS" method="checkLogin">
    <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">SectorDisplay</param>
        <param name="branch_id">${branch_id}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

parametes is sent as `branch_id` but its on `url` and it shows like

```
http://localhost:8085/Display/SectorDisplay.action?branch_id=110
```

I think its not as POST, its GET.

I do not want to show param on URL, is there any way to hide it or how can I post it to action?

Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you do a struts2 action redirect using POST instead of GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769005/can-you-do-a-struts2-action-redirect-using-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With redirection you can only pass `GET` parameters. You can use [action chaining](http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html) as an alternative.

Check these posts for details:

[Can you do a struts2 action redirect using POST instead of GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769005/can-you-do-a-struts2-action-redirect-using-post-instead-of-get)

[Struts 1 redirect from action to action with parameters as POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103749/struts-1-redirect-from-action-to-action-with-parameters-as-post-request)